# How to store column names to filter columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas

What is the best way to store column names in one file (and what type of file?) and if dataframe contains some of that columns from a file than select it (other columns would be dropped).
For example:

```
some_file_with_columns:
column_names = [col1, col3, col5, cola, colb, col6, colm]

Dataframes:
df1.columns= [col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7]
df2.columns= [cola, colb, colc, cold, colm, colp]
```

Desired Output after processing:

```
df1.columns= [col1, col3, col5, col6, ]
df2.columns= [cola, colb, colm]
```

Maybe yaml file? 
I am asking this because I have 9 dataframes that need to be prosecuted and they have altogether almost 300 columns. I would be happy if I could remove columns name from the script and store them in some separated file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `difference`

```
df=df[:,df.columns.difference(column_names)]
```

Comment: Yes, but what is the best way to store column_names, in yaml file? and then read and parse into python list?

Comment: @jovicbg just need df.columns to csv I think this is simple

Answer (score 1):

You have *many* options. Choose what makes most sense for your use case.

These options assume you have a list `lst` containing column names.

```
df_cols = pd.DataFrame({'col': lst})

# csv - text file which is widely read
df_cols.to_csv('file.csv')

# pickle - serialized data, readable by identical version pandas
df_cols.to_pickle('file.pkl')

# excel - readable via MS Excel
df_cols.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Then just read the files using `pandas` and convert to a list.